# Remote monitor of log files

Tags: linux, logs, remote-access, ssh

I looking for software to monitor multiple linux remote servers log files.

How I do it now?
Just open ssh client and tail the file what I want but you had to open terminal for every server and every file.

What I want?
Software where I define remote hosts and remote files, after run it should show multiple windows with tailed log files on remote servers.

What I found ?
katzgrau/chip [enter link description here](https://github.com/katzgrau/chip)
but it is project from 2014 and it is still in alpha. So there is something else what is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  bachelor thesis written by German computer professional [Jens Kühnel](https://www.it-hure.de/):

Short Blog Post: [Centralized and structured log file analysis with Open Source and Free Software tools](https://www.it-hure.de/2013/10/bachelor-thesis-centralized-and-structured-log-file-analysis-with-open-source-and-free-software-tools/)

Paper: [PDF, 0.5 MB](http://www.kuehnel.org/bachelor.pdf)

The paper is from 2013, written in English.

First half of the abstract:

> This thesis gives an overview on the Open Source and Free Software tools available for a centralized and structured log file analysis. This includes the tools to convert unstructured logs into structured log and different possibilities to transport this log to a central analyzing and storage station. The different storage and analyzing tools will be introduced, as well as the different web front ends to be used by the system administrator. At the end different tool chains will be introduced, that are well tested in this field.

I saw him giving a a talk about this, he seemed very competent.